# how do I get most of my standard linux utilities and commands on Android 3.1?

Tags: applications, linux, 3.1-honeycomb

by standard, i mean just what users often get by default with one of the popular distros.

for example, uname, finger, vim, tmux, etc.

I have a galaxy tab 10.1 (android version 3.1, already rooted)

Also, I read somewhere about setting up a chroot on android to run full-fledged linux distros, such as debian. Is that possible?

Comment: Android isn't a Linux distro, so these utilities are not standard at all.

Answer (score 5):

[BusyBox](https://market.android.com/details?id=stericson.busybox) for rooted devices gives many of Linux's standard utilities.

In terms of a real Linux distro, there are tons of How-Tos found on the web with a simple [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=install%20ubuntu%20on%20galaxy%20tab%2010.1&btnK=Google%20Search).  Specifically, here is a [step-by-step guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1172504) from XDA-Developers forum on building a Debian image for, and installing it on, the Galaxy Tab 10.1 tablet.